# viewWithTag method returns nil UILabel in viewDidLoad Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I got some strange behaviour of viewWithTag in viewDidLoad() method, 
I simply want to getting a label from storyboard with `tag` ,

I am using below code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   var getMyLabel : UILabel = self.view.viewWithTag(123) as UILabel
    getMyLabel.text = "test label"

 }
```

I have given correct tag in storyboard, show below image:
[image]

So how can i get Label from view's `viewWithTag` method?  in viewDidLoad() method.

P.S i try this in viewWillAppear method and that method it works, So what is the problem in viewDidLoad() ??

**Edit**

If i am Creating ViewController from Xib it works,
Problem is with storyboard.

Comment: Why don't you want to create an outlet instead?

Comment: There where many labels in view, i want to set some same property for all  and i don't want to gives outlet for all,

Comment: You can create an IBOutletCollection and attribute all of the labels to that outletCollection, then loop through them in your code. Would that work?

Comment: Show how you're creating the view controller instance

Comment: But what is wrong with viewWithTag property in viewDidLoad,

Comment: @Wain: `let lc : LabelVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LabelVC") as LabelVC
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(lc, animated: true)`

Comment: @Acey: Thanks for your suggestions , but that was not my question, i want to use it this property.

Comment: The problem is that viewWithTag ISN'T based on properties, it's based on random little numbers. It isn't very robust. It works in a pinch, but IBOutletCollections were made to specifically solve the problem of needing to reference many of the same things created in xib/storyboards.

Comment: At the time the `viewdidload` method is called the subviews is not yet attached to your view so you can refer to the

Comment: Understood. I was just trying to help. Hope you find your solution.

Comment: @FrancescoFrascà: but this is worked when i create view controller with xib. so what's wrong with storyboard?

Comment: @Acey: so is it bug or something?

Comment: Not sure. I just created a sample project and I am able to fetch a view with viewWithTag during viewDidLoad just fine.

Comment: :( so whats happen in my case..

Comment: @NetDemo In viewDidLoad the view is loaded but the subviews are not in place yet. Try to move the code to viewDidAppear.